# Firebird 3.0 on Ubuntu Xenial fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, firebird, firebird-3.0

I'm trying to install Firebird 3.0 on Ubuntu xenial. I'm using this command to check the server status:

```
Job for firebird3.0.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded
```

The answers is this:

```
    ● firebird3.0.service - Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer )
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firebird3.0.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sex 2016-07-01 14:52:03 BRT; 5min ago
  Process: 8596 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fbguard -pidfile /var/run/firebird/3.0default.pid -daemon -forever (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS

Jul 01 14:51:13 chriseana-Satellite-T115D systemd[1]: Starting Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer )...
Jul 01 14:51:13 chriseana-Satellite-T115D systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: PID file /var/run/firebird/3.0default.pid not readable (ye
Jul 01 14:52:03 chriseana-Satellite-T115D systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: Daemon never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Jul 01 14:52:03 chriseana-Satellite-T115D systemd[1]: Failed to start Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer ).
Jul 01 14:52:03 chriseana-Satellite-T115D systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 01 14:52:03 chriseana-Satellite-T115D systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

When I type:

```
/etc/init.d/firebird3.0 start
```

I receive this message:

```
[....] Starting firebird3.0 (via systemctl): firebird3.0.serviceJob for firebird3.0.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status firebird3.0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: I suggest you also post a question to the firebird-support mailinglist regarding this problem. BTW: The error message seems to be truncated (specifically the line _"firebird3.0.service: PID file /var/run/firebird/3.0default.pid not readable (ye"_). A [similar problem was posted there](https://www.mail-archive.com/firebird-support@yahoogroups.com/msg14479.html), which got the suggestion to use the Firebird built binaries instead of the one of the distribution.