# Job for firebird3.0.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firebird, ubuntu-16.04, firebird-3.0

Error when install and after when try to start Firebird 3.0 Service.

```
Job for firebird3.0.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status firebird3.0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

invoke-rc.d: initscript firebird3.0, action "start" failed.

dpkg: error processing package firebird3.0-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 firebird3.0-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

See return from "service firebird3.0 start":

```
Job for firebird3.0.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status firebird3.0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

See return from "journalctl -xe":

```
-- Unit firebird3.0.service has begun starting up.
Ago 26 15:41:22 server14 systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: PID file /var/run/firebird/3.0default.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Ago 26 15:41:22 server14 firebird[3509]: Security database error
Ago 26 15:41:22 server14 systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: Daemon never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Ago 26 15:41:22 server14 systemd[1]: Failed to start Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer ).
-- Subject: Unit firebird3.0.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit firebird3.0.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Ago 26 15:41:22 server14 systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: Unit entered failed state.
Ago 26 15:41:22 server14 systemd[1]: firebird3.0.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

I've tried many thing to solve but only way at moment is the manual start:

```
start-stop-daemon   --quiet --start --exec /usr/sbin/fbguard --pidfile /var/run/firebird/3.0/firebird.pid -b -m -- -daemon -forever -pidfile /var/run/firebird/3.0/firebird.pid
```

And manual stop:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --signal KILL --exec /usr/sbin/fbguard 
start-stop-daemon --stop --signal KILL --exec /usr/sbin/firebird
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `systemctl status firebird3.0.service` as was suggested in the error message? If so, could you please post this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151520/firebird-3-0-on-ubuntu-xenial-fails-to-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory /run/firebird/3.0 is not created on installation on debian based systems. So the systemd script does not work.

Workaround:

As user root do

1. create the directory: 
   mkdir -p /run/firebird/3.0
2. chown to firebird: 
   chown -R firebird:firebird /run/firebird

After doing this, firebird 3.0 should run as expected

As /run normally is an temporary directory in Debian, you could change the sytemd startup script to always execute directory creation before start of the service:

/lib/systemd/system/firebird3.0 should then look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer )
After=network.target
Conflicts=firebird3.0-classic.socket

[Service]
User=firebird
Group=firebird
Type=forking
# Run ExecStartPre with root-permissions
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir -p /run/firebird/3.0
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R firebird:firebird /run/firebird
PIDFile=/run/firebird/3.0/default.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fbguard -pidfile /run/firebird/3.0/default.pid -daemon -forever
RuntimeDirectory=firebird/3.0
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

PermissionsStartOnly=true is necessary to be able to execute all statements except the service itself (ExecStart) as root. This is important to create the subdirectories in /run.
BY the way: the - (minus) in the first ExecStartPre line makes run the script without stopping on errors returned from directory creation, helps if directory exists, for example after an service restart.

Don't forget to reload systemd:
    systemctl --system daemon-reload